# Access Jekyll Website across local wifi

Tags: web, wifi, jekyll

I have created a website with jekyll. Currently I am wanting to test my website across multiple devices/computers. I have seen some tutorials and they tell me to do this:

```
> jekyll serve --host 192.168.0.X
```

But... When I do that I receive an error code stating:

```
jekyll 3.1.1 | Error: The Requested address is not valid in its context.
- bind (2) for 192.168.0.X:4000
```

Any help?

~ Surprisejedi

p.s Oh yeah I replaced the ".X" with a number (if that confused you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message suggests that the IP of the computer where you are running `jekyll serve` is not `192.168.0.X`. Make sure you are binding to the same IP where Jekyll executes.

For testing purposes, you can also try to bind to all network interfaces i.e. `jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0`

Comment: *Facepalm* That makes so much sense now! Thanks!